# Struts 2: how to send url parameters in Action?

Tags: java, struts2

I try to send url parameter to Action class as described here: [How to access url parameters in Action classes Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582999/how-to-access-url-parameters-in-action-classes-struts-2)

If I do like next, it works and I can get pageLevel in Action class

```
<s:form action="index?pageLevel=99">
    <s:checkboxlist label="Select" list="colors" name="yourColor" value="defaultColor" />
    <s:submit value="Submit" /> 
</s:form>
```

But next does not work

```
<s:form action="index?pageLevel=<%=level%>">
```

And this does not work too

```
<c:set var="pageLevel" scope="page" value="<%=level%>" />
<s:form action="index?pageLevel=${pageLevel}">
```

I get error

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /start.jsp (line: 86, column: 0)
>   According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute action
>   does not accept any expressions

Jsp page contains

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do NOT use scriplets, parameters in `action` attribute of the form, and el expressions in S2 tags. USE hidden fields.

Comment: You can use struts url tag <s:url> to pass the parameter using <s:param> tag inside the url tag.<s:url action="urlTagAction.action" var="urlTag" >
    <s:param name="age">99</s:param>
</s:url>
<s:a href="%{urlTag}">URL Tag Action (via %)</s:a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<s:form action="index">
    <s:checkboxlist label="Select" list="colors" name="yourColor" value="defaultColor" />
    <s:hidden name="pageLevel" value="%{pageLevel}"/>
    <s:submit value="Submit" /> 
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Have a 'level' property in your index action with its getter an setter

Something like:

```
public class Index extends ActionSupport {

    private String level;

    public String getLevel() {
        return this.getLevel();
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }
}
```

1. Set 'level' as a hidden parameter in the form.

Assuming your action name is "index" and the request parameter is "pageLevel":

```
<s:form action="index">
    <s:checkboxlist label="Select" list="colors" name="yourColor" value="defaultColor" />
    <s:hidden name="level" value="%{#parameters.pageLevel}" />
    <s:submit value="Submit" /> 
</s:form>
```

Comment: nothingtodohere, 
ok, but how can I set request parameter from Action class if it return SUCCESS?

Comment: Is the result of this action the same page? if so you can access the 'level' using the level property value:

<s:property value="level" />